# Export multiple dataframes into .csv files

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, csv, export

I would like to export several dataframes as separate csv files to the working directory with a loop rather than writing out all of th names

```
##Sample data frame

employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
d30 <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)

##Creating a few of the same name for illustrative purposes
d39 <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)
d40 <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)

for (list in c(d30,d39)){
  write.csv(list, file="list.csv", row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Obviously I'm quite wrong. But I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over the data frame names.  We assume all names start with d and are of length 3.  Modify the pattern if not or directly set `nms` if you know them.  We also make a second check that the names are data frames but you can omit that check if you are sure that there are no objects that are not data frames and have a name matching the pattern.

```
nms <- ls(pattern = "^d..$")
for(nm in nms) {
  X <- get(nm)
  if (is.data.frame(X)) {
    filename <- paste0(nm, ".csv")
    message("writing out ", filename)
    write.csv(X, file = filename, row.names = FALSE)
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Unfortunately the data frame names don't follow a pattern as they did in my sample but I replaced this with a simple list of the data frame names. Out of curiosity, it there a quick way to generate a list of the names of all data frames in the global environment?

Comment: The code already rejects any name not representing a data frame so if you want all data frames in your workspace `nms <- ls()` would work.  `names(Filter(isTRUE, eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.data.frame)))` would give the names of all data frames but you don't really need it.

Answer (score 0):

```r
i <- 1

dfs <- list(d30, d39)

for (df in dfs){
  filename <- paste0("list", " ", i, ".csv")
  write.csv(list, file=filename, row.names = FALSE)
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
```

**Code:**

```
# create a new environment
myenv <- new.env()
# create data frames inside the environment
myenv$d30 <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)
myenv$d40 <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)

# get data from environment and write to files.
for (list in mget(ls(envir = myenv), envir = myenv)){
  write.csv(list, file="list.csv", row.names = FALSE)
}
```